# start processes with a delay

Tags: c#, process, delay

How can I start 5 different processes, each with their own delay without holding up the other ones while waiting for the delay to finish?
I can not use async or await

```
 foreach(string process1 in _processList)
  {
     // random delay
     Process.Start(process1);
    }
```

Comment: are you starting these processes from a win forms app, console app, web app?

Answer (score 3):

You could start every process from a different thread.

```
foreach (string process1 in _processList)
{
  Thread t = new Thread(() => 
           {
               Thread.Sleep(/*RANDOM NUMBER*/ 5);
               Process.Start(process1);
           });
  t.Start();
}
```

That way each process will have a random timer before it start and no process is delayed for the start of an other process.

If starting thread is totaly impossible in your situation, i would suggest wrapping your process to a .bat and in this batch file you add the sleep delay this way all the process will be called in time and the sleep delay will be respected.